# Create a relationship between two tables in PHP My Admin

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I currently have a MySQL databse with two tables, memebers and memberinfo.

I am using the members table for the user sessions and login, the table is as below:

```
||  ID  ||  USERNAME  ||  PASSWORD  || SALT ||
```

I then have another table with..

```
||  ID  ||  USERNAME  || FirstName  || Phone || Ect..
```

I will be adding lots of random coulmns to the second table and I dont want all of that data to be in the original members table so that it is kept puerly for logging the users in/out.

That being said, I want the tables to link, so that every time a new user is added via the php form, ID and Username are added to the member info table too.

Is this possible just in MySQL or will I have to tweak the PHP.

Thanks

Comment: So username in the second table is redundant

Comment: It's called a "foreign key"

Comment: MySQL is a S tructured Q uery L anguage. It's the Query that gives the Structure

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not a database

Comment: foreign keys aren't absolutely necessary. To relate a table, you just need a relationship. A relationship could be a single digit number in one field that relates to another table with the same digit in any field.

Comment: Foreign keys are really concerned with data integrity

Comment: If you want a table to have a relationship with another table you just have to give each a similar column that can be connected through JOIN queries. If you want an action like you described above learn how to write and use stored procedures. SP's can perform many actions at the same time and are quite good for what you describe. **Just the act of adding foreign keys will not cause one table to update another.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality you describe is only possible by using MySQL's [TRIGGER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html). You could setup a trigger that before the insert on the user table, it inserts into the user_info table. Although, I think most developers would align with using PHP and just insert twice. and use the returned insert_id.

But you will need some kind of a relation between the two tables otherwise this information will get lost in the tables. You would need a user_id column in your user_info table to link those two together. This doesn't HAVE to be a foreign key, but is a good example of when you can use one.